# Increase variable each time macro is used

Tags: phraseexpress

I have a few specific scenarios where I want to increase a variable (not temporary) each time I run a macro.

ie.
Used macro: This macro has been run 1 time(s). 
Used macro: This macro has been run 2 time(s).
Used macro: This macro has been run 3 time(s).

etc..

Seems pretty simple in theory but is this possible to accomplish with PhraseExpress?

Comment: You would store a file that tracks the number and then simply edit the file upon running

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. I found the option to embed a file, but I don't see a way for PhraseExpress to write output to a file.